# How to covert time based java.util.UUID to DateTIme

Tags: java, uuid

I'm using `com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs` to generate time based UUID but i can't convert the it back to date time:

I tried using `org.joda.time` but any other package is fine.

```
new org.joda.time.DateTime(com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.timeBased.timestamp) // 4328915-05-22T15:34:30.000+00:00
new org.joda.time.DateTime()  //2015-06-25T13:28:07.249+00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [`UUID`JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#timestamp--), the resulting timestamp is measured in 100-nanosecond units since midnight, October 15, 1582 UTC.

`org.joda.time.DateTime(long instant)` expects a timestamp in milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, see [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#constructor_summary)  .